# Inheritance in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine

I've already had a diagram class in which I have `ClassA` (superClass) and two classes `ClassB` and `ClassC` which inherit from `ClassA`. **How can I code them in Symfony2 using Doctrine?**

NB : When I'd generated entities with classical method (I mean with `doctrine:generate:entity`), I got three tables in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use single table for 3 classes, you should use DiscriminatorMap

Example: We have a class Product, and two child classes Coupon and CustomProduct that inherited from Product

```
/**
 * MyApp\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="productType", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *   "Product" = "Product",
 *   "Coupon" = "MyApp\CouponBundle\Entity\Coupon",
 *   "CustomProduct" = "MyApp\CustomProductBundle\Entity\CustomProduct",
 * })
 */
class Product implements PriceInterface
{
...
}
```

MyApp\CouponBundle\Entity\Coupon

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Coupon extends Product implements ProductInterface
{
}
```

MyApp\CusomProductBundle\Entity\CustomProduct

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CustomProduct extends Product implements ProductInterface
{
}
```

It will allow to use common table "product" for all 3 classes, the filed "productType" will have class name for stored record. More info http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

**Update for your question about 2 tables:**

You can specify separate tables for inherited classes as:

MyApp\CouponBundle\Entity\Coupon

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="coupon")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Coupon extends Product implements ProductInterface
{
}
```

MyApp\CusomProductBundle\Entity\CustomProduct

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="custom_product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CustomProduct extends Product implements ProductInterface
{
}
```

Comment: If I code my entities in such way. How much tables i will get in my database 2 or 3 ?

Comment: you will have 1 table "product"

Comment: Is there another way that allow me to get two `tables` Coupon and CustomProduct ? indeed, i wanna find super class attributes in child classes when i generate my tables

Comment: should I keep the same definition of super Class ?